# I want to upload the image and render it two second page as well as showing the thumbnail image also and create folder structure of users and images

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

THis my console error when i am trying to upload the image it will show this error
plz help me out for this situation i want to render the image on second page showing its thumbnail also and at runtime it will create the folder structure users and subfolder image

```
 hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
    hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
    [name=Desert.jpg, StoreLocation=D:\testing\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\uploadimg\upload__26aeaf5b_1425b674704__8000_00000000.tmp, size=845941bytes, isFormField=false, FieldName=file]
    hello nhi aaya
    mein aaya bahar le k
    yaha pe aaja 
    **Desert.jpg
    Desert.jpg
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\testing\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\uploadimg\users\images\Desert.jpg (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:439)
        at com.vaibhav.upload.doPost(upload.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) 

upload.java

    package com.vaibhav;

    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
    import org.imgscalr.Scalr;

    public class upload extends HttpServlet {
        private boolean isMultipart;
        String ofileName;
        String fieldName;
        String contentType;
        File usersDir = null;
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
            System.out.println("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");
            if (!isMultipart) {
            } else {

                File fobj = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("\\"));
                FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(1024 * 5, fobj);
                ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
                List items = null;
                System.out.println("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
                try {
                    items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                } catch (FileUploadException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(items);
                Iterator itr1 = items.iterator();
                System.out.println("hello nhi aaya");
                FileItem fileItem = null;

                while (itr1.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println("mein aaya bahar le k");
                    FileItem item = (FileItem) itr1.next();
                    if (item.isFormField()) {
                        item.getFieldName();
                        item.getString();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("yaha pe aaja ");

                        fileItem = item;
                        String finalName;
                        int namestart;
                        fieldName = item.getFieldName();System.out.println("**"+item.getName());
                        ofileName = item.getName();
                        contentType = fileItem.getContentType();
                        System.out.println(ofileName);
                        namestart = ofileName.lastIndexOf("//");
                        if (namestart > -1) {
                            finalName = ofileName.substring(namestart);
                        } else {
                            finalName = ofileName;  // there's nothing to substring
                        }
                        usersDir = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("\\")
                                + "\\users\\" + "\\images\\" + finalName);
                        try {
                            fileItem.write(usersDir);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        String imgExt = usersDir.getAbsolutePath().substring(
                                usersDir.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                        BufferedImage bimg = new BufferedImage(100, 100,
                                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                        bimg.createGraphics().drawImage(
                                ImageIO.read(usersDir).getScaledInstance(170, 150,
                                        java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), 0, 0, null);
                        BufferedImage bimg2 = Scalr.resize(bimg, 150);
                        ImageIO.write(bimg2, imgExt, new File(getServletContext()
                                .getRealPath("\\")
                                + "\\users\\"
                                + "\\images\\thumb_" + finalName));
                    }
                    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/webpages/home.jsp");
                    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

......................................................................................
index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>file upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" size="50"><br/> <input
            type="submit" value="uploadfile">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where do you have the images can u share the folder structure your error is because D:\testing\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\uploadimg\users\images\Desert.jpg this location does not contain desert.jpg image. Have you tried ServletContext.getContextPath()?

Comment: lakshmi  i am trying to upload tha image using apache commons file upload  C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\ desertpicture..included the jsp file  also

Comment: where are u trying to save the picture ur file is trying to be saved in D:\testing\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\upload‌​img\users\images\Desert.jpg is this location correct?

Comment: Please try printing System.out.println(getServletContext().getRealPath("/"));

Comment: yes this is the location where my image is stored here and its thumbnail also but why it is showing file not found exception even folder is also not created above is my code ...i take the help  from apache commons fileupload

Comment: while saving the image using imageIO instead of file write

Comment: instead of this 

    usersDir = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("\\")
                                    + "\\users\\" + "\\images\\" + finalName);
try

 usersDir = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("\\")
                                + "\\users\\" + "\\images\\" ,finalName);

Answer (score 0):

Your application unable to find folder "users/images".

Either go to your project where "index.jsp" is located 
and (at same level) create folder "users" and create one more folder "images" under it.
( in other words inside "uploadimg" folder )

or else

Don't use "\users\" + "\images\""in your code.